# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 - C# PDB file corrupt - shows wrong line numbers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pdb-files, corrupt

I have a problem with a single C# project in a solution of 21 C# projects (ANY CPU).

Break points aren't hit - and when I force the debugger to attach (Debugger.Launch()), I can see that the call stack shows the correct functions however the line numbers are very wrong.

In a concrete example, I have a break point in line 346 of 1020 lines - but the debugger navigates to line 10745 which results in the debugger showing results from a totally different file. From log files I can see that the correct methods are being executed.

After much headache I therefore chose to try on 2 different machines with VS 2010 SP1 installed - and these showed the exact same behavior.

I have already tried to do a full clean of the solution, manually delete all PDB files, restart VS, restart the machine, emptied the VS Symbol Cache (Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols), removed all "Symbol file (.pdb) locations" and delete the solution's ".SDF" database.

I am compiling the project in Debug mode, and have verified that "Optimize code" is not enabled on the project.

Break points in different projects in the solution does work - so it seems it is only this one project that for some reason generates a corrupt PDB file. However, I can't really see why this single project should differ from the other projects. The only real difference is that I have 2 web references in this particular project - and funny enough it is in these stub classes that the PDB file always instructs the debugger to end up.

The particular solution is being compiled and debugged on a fully patched Windows 2003 x86 machine.

I would appreciate if anyone could give me a hint how to solve this problem.

Comment: Just a thought, rename the web references and try again.

Comment: Tried this - no luck - same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right click on the project, go to the build tab->click advanced button->check output area->select debug info to pbd-only. Sometimes it changes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, appreciate it. However, no luck - same behavior. It was on "full", changed it to "pdb-only" which didn't solve the problem, why I have changed it back to "full" again.

Comment: Do you think the environment has something run? Or some cache stuff. Also try to remove the bin and obj folder and recompile again.

Comment: I have tried to clear everything I could think of - including deleting the bin and obj folders. I think that it may be a bug in VS that for some reason generates invalid PDB files. Don't know why it suddenly happened - have been working without a problem on the project for 1½ years. Haven't done anything out of the ordinary, just modified a single method by adding 6 lines of code. And yes, in desperation I have tried to remove this modification but with the same result.

Comment: I agree, if you have a team foundation server, you can verify if it's the solution issue or a configuration issue. Or go to another machine to see if it's a VS bug. You have tried what I have thought though.

Comment: I remember one time I meet this kind of issue, I went to "Configuration Manager" and make sure the active solution platform is "Any CPU" and then make sure all the build checkbox is checked. You can also try this one.

Comment: I have already checked this - and everything appears to be correctly configured. I have also tried to compile on 4 different machines - all with the same result. Only difference was that when I compiled the solution on a Windows 7 x64 - instead of navigating to the non-existing line 10745 it navigated to the non-existing line 24994!

Comment: Problem solved! It was a malfunctioning postbuild event that in some way confused the debugger. Although it has been used with success on other projects, this particular project didn't like this postbuild event for some reason.

Comment: What seemed to do the trick for me was cleaning the PDB cache (options->debugging->symbols), and correcting the pdb search order in that screen.